# Synchronization and hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have an application with hibernate. There are two main threads, first one is collecting/modifying data and second one is saving data into database, in certain cases the program may try to modify and save the entity at same time.

Do i have to make all entities thread-safe (use only synchronized collections, atomic objects instead of primitives...) or hibernate takes care about it automatically?

Comment: You need a Hibernate session per conversation. You should not share the session between threads and therefore entities need not be synchronized.

Comment: And if i need to save data during the session i have to synchronize my entities?

Comment: My recommendation to you is that take some time to read the book [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/). But the short answer if you have one session per conversation than synchronization won't help you because the entities from one session are different than the entities of the other one, even if they refer to the same database record. In those cases you need to solve the problem in a different way, using optimistic or pessimistic locking. But as you can guess, that's hard to explain here. Go read that book that will help you more than asking any question here.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate instantiates objects per session, so classic synchronization is not needed (and would not be helpful).

The most common way to take care of concurrent data access and modifications is to use [locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html).